# Disable responsiveness for Sidebar template

Tags: jquery, html, css, sidebar

I'm using this sidebar with some customized CSS for my page (http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/)

I want it to disable responsiveness, but I do not see how to do it.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/Lare73s4/) is my custom CSS for it, maybe I'm overseeing something?

It's probably something with this, but maybe not

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 0 0 50px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
z-index: 1000;
position: absolute;
right: 250px;
width: 0;
height: 100%;
margin-right: 0%;
overflow-y: auto;
background: #000;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

}

Note: I'm aware it looks horrible and overshadows the text, but I use a different HTML for my page. I just need the bar to remain where it is and not be responsive!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the media query at the bottom of your CSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lare73s4/ @ starting at line 133 until the end of the file.

If you save it you'll notice that your sidebar has disappeared, easy fix: back at the top of your css, change the `width` property of the #sidebar-wrapper block.

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 0 0 50px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    right: 250px;
    width: 250px; /* I added 250px here, originally it's 0 */
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

The media query we removed was `@media(min-width:768px) {` which means that as long as the window is at least 768px, apply these styles declared in the block. In there the `#sidebar-wrapper` selector has a declaration of `width`:

```
@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px; /* here!!! */
    }
...
```

So since we removed it, there are no longer extra requirements for styles to be set.

Here is working code: https://jsfiddle.net/1tbdn8oo/

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much! I did actually remove the media part, but like you said, the bar disappeared, I was just missing that! Thank you so much!
However, is it there a way to make the bar fixed where it is? If I start shrinking my browser, the bar will move around. Is there a way to make it stationary where it is?

Comment: You would have to remove any relative values like if you're using any `%` values instead of pixels, change it to be pixels :]